# Hatcher's proof of Poincare Duality

Tags: algebraic-topology, poincare-duality

[Thm. 3.35, pg245](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf). The proof begins 247-248.

Hatcher defines a duality map 
$$D:H^k_c(M;R) \rightarrow H_{n-k}(M;R) $$ 
where the LHS is compactly supported cohomology. An element can be represented by $\varphi \in H^k(M,M-K:R)$, $K \subseteq M$ compact.

The map is given by $D_M [\varphi] = \varphi[M|_K]$, where $M|_K$ is fundamental class of $H_n(M,M-K;R)$.

---

In line 10 p.248, Hatcher claims that this map, when $M=\Bbb R^n\simeq Int \Delta^n$ , can be identified with 
$$D_M:H^k(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n) \rightarrow H_{n-k}(\Delta^n)$$

How so?

Comment: So first of all the RHS identification should be clear due to $\mathbb{R}^n=Int\Delta^n$ and both being contractible. So what is Hatcher saying is that $H^k_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be identified with $H^k(\Delta^n, \partial\Delta^n)$. This is an algebraic analogy to the geometric fact that every compactly supported function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be seen as a function on $\Delta^n$ that is $0$ on (some open neighbourhood of) $\partial\Delta^n$. For details I think you need to dive into definitions. I'll think about it tomorrow and get back to you hopefuly.

Comment: The above comment explains it in a nice intuition. The following can be proved via collar neighborhoods(see Proposition 3.42): If $M$ is a compact manifold with boundary, then $H^k_c(M-\partial M) \cong H^k(M,\partial M)$. (This is easy, since every compact set $K$ in $M- \partial M$ is contained in some $M- \partial M \times (0,\varepsilon)$. See also the definition of $H^k_c(X)$ in terms of direct limits, which is explained below Proposition 3.33.) Your question is the special case $M=\Delta^n$.